# broadcast each row of A along B, avoiding `repeat`

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have 2 2D arrays, with 1 axis of the same dimension:

```
a = np.array(np.arange(6).reshape((2,3)))
b = np.array(np.arange(12).reshape((3,4)))
```

I want to multiply and broadcast each row of `a` with `b`, that is

```
b_r = np.repeat(b[:,:,None], 2, axis=2)
ab = a.T[:,None,:] * b_r
```

Is it possible to do the broadcasting while avoiding the `repeat`? The idea is to avoid unnecessary memory allocation for the `repeat` operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just feed in `b[:,:,None]` without the repeat, as [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) with its very definition would broadcast it for you.

Thus, simply do -

```
ab = a.T[:,None,:]*b[:,:,None]
```

We can make it a bit compact though by skipping the trailing `:` for `a` and using `...` to replace `:,:` for `b`, like so -

```
ab = a.T[:,None]*b[...,None]
```

---

For the *kicks*, here's one using [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), which would be little less performant, but more expressive once we get past its string notation -

```
ab = np.einsum('ij,jk->jki',a,b)
```